# generated protocol buffers class in Python : Module Not Found

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I am generating python classes with `protoc -I=$SRC_DIR --python_out=$DST_DIR $SRC_DIR/addressbook.proto` command which I found in the official [doc](protoc -I=$SRC_DIR --python_out=$DST_DIR $SRC_DIR/UserId.proto), as well as with the `--pyi_out` flag (I found this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71960226/protocol-buffers-in-python-no-classes-generated) )

The code is part of a git submodule. Installing the submodule does not copy the `.pyi` file therefore I am not able to import the generated classes when using the submodule.

How can I structure the code so that the classes are available to other repos ? Do I need to somehow generate protobuf classes each time I update the submodule for a new virtual environment?

Comment: It seems your link to the documentation may be broken. Could you please add that?

Comment: You say "I don't get any errors in VS Code", and then you immediately say that you get a `ModuleNotFoundError`.  This is confusing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I edited my question. I am using git submodules which ignores pyi files apparently which is why i am not able to import classes